# How can I call a class function for my custom plugin after settings are updated?

Tags: wordpress

I've got a basic settings page for my plugin that's working well to store settings.  However, i want to trigger an api call by calling a function within my plugin class after they are updated.  I've tried several angles to get this to work but no luck.  Help?

```
function pf404_options_page() {     
 add_submenu_page(
    'options-general.php',
    'PF 404 Settings',
    'PF 404',
    'manage_options',
    'pf404',
    'pf404_options_page_html'
 );
} 
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'pf404_options_page' );

function pf404_options_page_html() {

 if ( ! current_user_can( 'manage_options' ) ) {
 return;
 } 

 // show error/update messages
 settings_errors( 'pf404_messages' );
 ?>
 <div class="wrap">
 <h1><?php echo esc_html( get_admin_page_title() ); ?></h1>
 <form action="<?php echo admin_url( 'options.php' ); ?>" method="post">
 <?php wp_nonce_field(); ?>
 <?php
 // output security fields for the registered setting "pf404"
 settings_fields( 'pf404' );
 // output setting sections and their fields
 // (sections are registered for "pf404", each field is registered to a specific section)
 do_settings_sections( 'pf404' );
 // output save settings button
 submit_button( 'Save Settings' );

 ?>
 </form>
 </div>
 <?php
} ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured this out by myself and used

```
register_setting( 'pf404', 'pf404_options', 'sanitize_function' );

function sanitize_function($input){

    myclass::load_api_data($input['pf404_field_apikey'], $input['pf404_field_animal']);         
    return $input;
}
```

I was unable to access the class function i wanted to call unless it was set to static.